# How to save location data in without using a database?

Tags: java, android, file, save, location

I'm currently coding an app that locates the mobile device and computes the speed between locations. 
I want to save these locations with certain informations like the timestamp without using a database. 
In deep, Im using location.speed when GPS is avaialble and if not I'm using network, which has no speed and needs to be computed afterwards. 
I want to use this to track speed while I ride my bike.

Everything is done except the way of saving my results.
I thought about creating a txt file or something automatically containing my data or using a interface like bluetooth to send the information. Since I do long bike rides, that way should be solid to save or transfer a lot of data.

Any ideas and ways to do that?

Comment: You could use a standard for the files like .gpx or .kml

Comment: `... solid to save or transfer a lot of data` Then you're not seriously talking about a text file. Your best option for `a lot of data` is a database (even a local one, like SQLite)

Answer (score 0):

You can create and store JSON File that corresponding to ur result object.
Then you can store files in local data storage of your mobile phone or in third party like REST API

Answer (score 0):

You can check any logging library that will store your data into file.You can share that file via API or manually.

Sample lib https://github.com/johanlkarlsson/microlog4android